# Ruby on Rails custom FormBuilder override text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, formbuilder

I have a custom form builder in my project using the following code in an initializer:

```
class CustomFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

  def submit(label, *args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    new_class = options[:class] || "btn"
    super(label, *(args << options.merge(:class => new_class)))
  end

  def text_field(label, *args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    new_class = options[:class] || "textbox"
    super(label, *(args << options.merge(:class => new_class)))
  end

end

# Set CustomBuilder as default FormBuilder
ActionView::Base.default_form_builder = CustomFormBuilder
```

The *submit* definition works and appends the class **btn** to submit inputs, however the *text_field* definition doesn't seem to work as the class **textbox** does not get appended to text inputs.

After looking at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html) for FormBuilder I noticed that *submit* is listed as a method while *text_field* is not. What I need to figure out is how to correctly override the *text_field* method used when generating forms using *form_for*. In case it helps I am using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 3.2.13. Also I looked at an example [here](http://www.likeawritingdesk.com/posts/very-custom-form-builders-in-rails) which shows the *text_field* method in the custom FormBuilder class so I wonder if in Rails 3 this method was removed from *FormBuilder* and put somewhere else. Any insight in how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

**Below is my solution** *(based on the information given by PinnyM)*:

```
class CustomFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

  def submit(label, *args)
    options = args.extract_options!
    options[:class] = "btn" if !options[:class].present?
    super(label, *(args << options))
  end

  def self.create_tagged_field(method_name)
    case method_name
    when 'text_field'
      define_method(method_name) do |name, *args|
        options = args.extract_options!
        options[:class] = "textbox" if !options[:class].present?
        super(name, *(args << options))
      end
    end
  end

  field_helpers.each do |name|
    create_tagged_field(name)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FormBuilder` uses meta-code to generate the methods for most form tags (including `text_field`).  It borrows the `FormHelper` instance methods for this purpose, excludes specific tags that require a different implementation, and loops through the remaining tags to auto-generate methods for them.  The relevant code that does the generation looks like this:

```
(field_helpers - %w(label check_box radio_button fields_for hidden_field file_field)).each do |selector|
  class_eval <<-RUBY_EVAL, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def #{selector}(method, options = {}) # def text_field(method, options = {})
      @template.send( # @template.send(   
        #{selector.inspect}, # "text_field",
        @object_name, # @object_name,
        method, # method,
        objectify_options(options)) # objectify_options(options))
    end # end
    RUBY_EVAL
end
```